# The projection $\mathsf{Top}_*\to h\sf Top_*$ preserves products

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, category-theory, homotopy-theory

**Preliminary fact**.

Let $d:\sf I\to Set$ be a diagram of sets ($\sf I$ is a small category). Suppose that (1) for any object $i$ in $\sf I$, is given an equivalence relation $\sim_i$ on the set $d(i)$, and that (2) for any arrow $l:i\to i'$ in $\sf I$, if $x,x'\in d(i)$ satisfy $x\sim_ix'$, then $d(l)(x)\sim_{i'} d(l)(x')$. Let $t(i):=d(i)/\sim _i$, and let $t(l):t(i)\to t(i')$ be the map induced by $d(l)$; denote by $t:\sf  I\to Set$ the diagram obtained.

Observe that the relations $\sim _i$ yield an equivalence relation $\sim$ on $\prod_{i\in ob(\mathsf I)}d(i)$, and moreover $\prod_{i\in ob(\mathsf I)}d(i)/\sim$ is equal to $\prod_{i\in ob(\mathsf I)}t(i)$.

Now consider $\lim d$, which is a subset of $ \prod_{i\in ob(\mathsf I)}d(i)$. $\sim$ induces an equivalence relation on $\lim d$, which we denote again $\sim$, but it isn't true, in general, that $\lim d/\sim $ is equal to $\lim t$.

Finally let $S$ be a set and $f:S\to \prod_{i\in ob(\mathsf I)}d(i)$ be a map. Suppose that there is an equivalence relation $\sim_S$ on $S$, and that, if $s,s'\in S$ satisfy $s\sim _S s'$, then $f(s)\sim f(s')$. If $f$ induces a bijection $S\to \lim d$, it induces a bijection $S/\sim_S\to \lim d/\sim$, and in case that $\sf I$ is discrete, this is a bijection $S/\sim_S\to \lim t$.

**Question**.

Let $\sf Top$ be the category of topological spaces. Recall that two continuous maps $f,g\in \mathsf {Top}(X,Y)$ are said *homotopic* if there is a continuous map $H:X\times I\to Y$ such that $H(x,0)=f(x)$ and $H(x,1)=g(x)$, for all $x\in X$. Homotopy is an equivalence relation, which respects composition: then let $h\sf Top$ be the quotient category of $\sf Top$ by the homotopy relation.

Let $\{X_i\}_{i\in I}$ be a family of topological spaces, and consider the product $X:=\prod_{i\in I}X_i$, with the canonical maps $p_i:X\to X_i$. There is a natural bijection $\mathsf{Top}(-,X)\Rightarrow \prod_{i\in I}\mathsf{Top}(-,X_i)$, defined by composition with the $p_i$. The last paragraph of the preliminary fact shows that:

- it is induced a bijection $h\mathsf{Top}(Y,X)\to \prod_{i\in I}h\mathsf{Top}(Y,X_i)$ at all $Y$ (hence a natural bijection $h\mathsf{Top}(-,X)\Rightarrow \prod_{i\in I}h\mathsf{Top}(-,X_i)$, i.e. the projection $\mathsf {Top}\to h\sf Top$ preserves products);
- the point above may not be true replacing the product with another limit.

If instead of $\sf Top$ we work with the category of pointed spaces, and use pointed homotopy, and want to prove that $\pi:\mathsf{Top}_*\to h\sf Top_*$ preserves products, I don't see what could go differently from above. In  Tammo tom Diecks' *Algebraic Topology*, page 31, is suggested to show that $\pi$ preserves products using this result (*Proposition 2.1.6* on the book):

> If $p:X\to Y$ is a quotient map of topological spaces, and $H:Y\times I\to Z$ is a map of sets such that $H\circ (p\times \mathrm{id}): X\times I\to Z$ is continuous, then $H$ is continuous.

Do you think that my proof is ok? I fear not, because I wouldn't see how to link the indented result to $\pi$ preserving products, and I don't think it is used implicitly in my proof somewhere. Maybe my argument works in $\sf Top$, but not in $\sf Top_*$? But as I said, I can't see where it fails. Thanks for any clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need 2.1.6 for the (pointed and unpointed) product case nor for the unpointed sum case, but you need it to prove that $\pi:\mathsf{Top}_*\to h\sf Top_*$ preserves sums. This is what tom Dieck says:

> The sum and the product in TOP$^0$ also represent the sum and the product in h-TOP$^0$ (use (2.1.6)).

The problem is this:

Each family of pointed homotopies $H_j : (X_j,*) \times I \to (Y,*)$ induces a function $H : (\bigvee_ j(X_j,*)) \times I   \to (Y,*)$. Show that $H$ is continuous.

The wedge $\bigvee_ j(X_j,*)$ is the quotient of the disjoint sum $\coprod_j X_j$ obtained by identifying all basepoints of the $X_j$ to a single point. Clearly the $H_j$ induce a continuous $\tilde H : (\coprod_j X_j) \times I  \to Y$, and now we need 2.1.6 to see that $H$ is continuous.